# How to parse a string to words?

Tags: string, algorithm, nlp

How to parse text such as

**"Text segmentation is the process of dividing written text into meaningful units, such as words, sentences, or topics. --Mr.Wikipedia"**

to

**Words=["Text","segmentation","is","the","process","of","dividing","written","text","into","meaningful","units","such","as","words","sentences","or","topics","Mr.Wikipedia]"**

I've already tried replacement techniques but i ended up with several contiguous spaces.

Comment: Wow i must be tired, i read nlp as php and added a whole answer before realizing its not php

Comment: Any way post the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you code in Python, use [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) (refer to [NLTK book](http://nltk.org/book/ch03.html))

```
import nltk
sentence = "Text segmentation is the process of dividing written text into meaningful units, such as words, sentences, or topics. --Mr.Wikipedia"
words = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
```

For Java try [OpenNLP tokenizer](http://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/manual/opennlp.html#tools.tokenizer.cmdline)